# Automatically send text every 10 seconds

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program that gets the app name, place them on a listbox and sends them to the other window if you click the send button.

What I wanted to know is, is it possible for it to automatically send every 10 seconds after a single click on the send button? If yes, how can I possibly do that?

There's the codes, in case if it brings of any help.

```
private void cmd_send_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String processID = "";
    String processName = "";
    String processFileName = "";
    String processPath = "";
    string hostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();

    listBox1.BeginUpdate();
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            piis = GetAllProcessInfos();

            try
            {
               // String pno = textBox4.Text.ToString();
               // String path = textBox5.Text.ToString();
               // String name = textBox6.Text.ToString();
               // String user = textBox7.Text.ToString();
               // output.Text += "\n Sent data : " + pno + " " + user + " " + name + " " + path ;

                processID = piis[i].Id.ToString();
                processName = piis[i].Name.ToString();
                processFileName = piis[i].FileName.ToString();
                processPath = piis[i].Path.ToString();
                output.Text += "\n\nSENT DATA : \n\t" + processID + "\n\t" + processName + "\n\t" + processFileName + "\n\t" + processPath + "\n";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                wait.Abort();
                output.Text += "Error..... " + ex.StackTrace;
            }

            NetworkStream ns = tcpclnt.GetStream();
            String data = "";
            //data = "--++" + "  " + textBox4.Text + " " + textBox5.Text + " " + textBox6.Text + " " + textBox7.Text;
            data = "--++" + "  " + processID + " " + processPath + " " + processFileName + " " + hostName;
            if (ns.CanWrite)
            {
                byte[] bf = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(data);
                ns.Write(bf, 0, bf.Length);
                ns.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        listBox1.EndUpdate();
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use System.Timer.  Set Interval to 10000, you button click should create and start the timer and you event should call the method your button click currently calls

Comment: Is your current code sends only one time when button click? correct?

Comment: @Mehmood Yes. Only one time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could place your code inside a single method, call that method initially on button click and start/stop your timer depending on it's current state.

```
private Timer _timer;

public Form() // Initialize timer in your form constructor
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _timer = new Timer();
    _timer.Interval = 10000; // miliseconds
    _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick; // Subscribe timer to it's tick event
}

private void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendData();
}

private void cmd_send_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!_timer.Enabled) // If timer is not running send data and start refresh interval
    {
        SendData();
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }
    else // Stop timer to prevent further refreshing
    {
        _timer.Enabled = false;
    }
}

private void SendData()
{
    // Your code here
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you're using .NET framework 4.5 or above you can do the same thing in using `async/await`.

```
private bool keepRefreshing;
private async void cmd_send_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (keepRefreshing)
    {
        keepRefreshing = false;
        return;
    }

    keepRefreshing = true;
    while (keepRefreshing)
    {
        // Your code here
        await Task.Delay(10000);
    }
}
```

On button click it will send data and it will keep sending with delay of 10 seconds. When you press the button second time it will stop refreshing interval, third time it will start again and so on..

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir. Tried your code but it seems like it has a problem with the 'Timer'. 
'Timer' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer' and 'System.Threading.Timer'
Please help me out sir. @msmolcic

Comment: @helpmeplease That's because you included using System.Threading; when you tried out Thread.Sleep(10000); solution below. There is Threading.Timer and Windows.Forms.Timer class and I used Forms.Timer in this Example. So, either remove using System.Threading from the begining of your cs file or add System.Windows.Forms.Timer prefix where I used private Timer and where I created new Timer();

Answer (score 2):

```
// Declare a timer
Timer tmr = new Timer();

tmr.Interval = 10000; // 10 second
tmr.Tick += timerHandler; // We'll write it in a bit
tmr.Start(); // The countdown is launched!

private void timerHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Here the code what you need each 10 seconds
    tmr.Stop(); // Manually stop timer, or let run indefinitely
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Their are many ways one is follow.

```
private void cmd_send_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool isResend=true;
    while (isResend==true)
    {
         // Put all your here
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
}
```

Other ways are using Timer, etc...

Comment: thanks for the quick reply sir. Tried this code and yes it worked but the problem is it hangs up the program. Help me out sir.

Comment: @helpmeplease It hangs out because you stop the whole UI thread when you put it to sleep, it's not a good solution. Check out my answer.

Comment: You can also check @msmolcic answer for timer.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone's answer is cool, but as for me if you really need that "click" as start, i'll do it this way.

1. Initiate events for timer & background worker inside form load.
2. set timer.start(); inside click.
3. Once ticking, if backgroundworker is not busy, execute background worker.
4. Ensure that you don't directly set label1.text = "send some works here." inside the background worker, it will cause error.

Hope this helps.

[image]